# Release Management Client can't see Deployment Agent Heart Beat

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, ms-release-management

After Installing the Release Management Client, I tried to connect it to a server with the Deployment Agent installed. In the Servers list in Configure Paths the Deployer Status is saying that it can't connect to the Deployment Agent as the Heart Beat can not be found. On cheching the Event Log on the Deployment Agent machine I get the following. How do I ensure the server\client can see the Heart Beat?

```
Timestamp: 04/07/2014 11:27:11
Message: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\bin\DeploymentAgentUpdaterExe' is denied.: \r\n\r\n   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.HeartBeat.UpdateDeployer()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.HeartBeat.CheckForUpdates()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.HeartBeat.SendHeartBeat()
Category: General
Priority: -1
EventId: 0
Severity: Error
Title:
Machine: CSR-PIZZA6-TEST
Application Domain: DeploymentAgent.exe
Process Id: 3516
Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\bin\DeploymentAgent.exe
Win32 Thread Id: 764
Thread Name: 
Extended Properties:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN documentation says that the identity that the Deployment Agent is running under requires a variety of things:

"The deployment agent uses this identity to configure this machine for your release. Make sure the identity you use here has enough permission to do whatever tasks are required. For example, if you need to install your application on this machine as part of your release, add this identity to the local Windows Administrators security group. If this identity will need to access builds on the network, make sure it has access to the network drop location."

I added the Service Identity to the local Windows Administrators security group and all worked.

[Install deployment agent and set up an environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn593701.aspx)